# How to drop shipping cost when billing company is set in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I waive the shipping cost when the Billing Company field is not empty in the checkout page?
What I've tried:

```
function test_wc_shipping_cost_tiers( $cost, $method ) {

    if ( isset(WC()->order->get_billing_company) ) {
        $cost = 0;
    }
    return $cost;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_rate_cost', 'test_wc_shipping_cost_tiers', 10, 2 );
```

But it does not waive the shipping cost when I enter a name in the Billing Company field..

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using the `empty()` method instead of `isset()`.
While **empty()** checks if the field has any value in it or not, you can think of **isset()** as checking of the field exists.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't `WC()->order` only exist once the order has already been raised? If you are doing this on the checkout page that means that the order does not exist as of yet, only the checkout does, that too would only hold values on the front end as the user has not submitted them to the site yet. Unless you have a custom implementation in place, both the shipping and the billing fields exist on the same page that means that you'll probably have to:
1. Display your free shipping on checkout using JS and 2. Make it actually free using some PHP after the form is submitted.